# BatchNorm momentum convention PyTorch

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, pytorch, batch-normalization

Is the [batchnorm momentum convention](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/_modules/torch/nn/modules/batchnorm.html) (default=0.1) correct as in other libraries e.g. Tensorflow it seems to usually be 0.9 or 0.99 by default? Or maybe we are just using a different convention?

Comment: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/batch-norm-momentum-default-value/11955

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It seems that the parametrization convention is different in pytorch than in tensorflow, so that 0.1 in pytorch is equivalent to 0.9 in tensorflow.

To be more precise:

In Tensorflow:

```
running_mean = decay*running_mean + (1-decay)*new_value
```

In PyTorch:

```
running_mean = (1-decay)*running_mean + decay*new_value
```

This means that a value of `decay` in PyTorch is equivalent to a value of `(1-decay)` in Tensorflow.