# Batch normalization seems to not work same in keras and pytorch

Tags: tensorflow, keras, pytorch, batch-normalization

I am having a simple model and trying out how batch normalization works, applying after linear layer. It seem to not normalize at all, as by default it is initialized to identity in keras. After checking with the same weights in pytorch, its batch normalization does make changes. Please see below. Why and what is wrong in the model?

Edit: self-contained example which prints results both from keras and pytorch model for visual comparison. To use batchnormalization layer, please uncomment few lines that are pointing it out, then compare the results again.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from collections import OrderedDict

from tensorflow.python.keras import layers 
from tensorflow.python.keras import models

import torch
from torch import nn
from torch.nn import functional as F


from tensorflow.contrib import eager as tfe
tfe.enable_eager_execution()


class PytorchModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,
                 in_channels,
                 out_channels):
        super().__init__()

        self.linear = nn.Linear(in_channels, out_channels, bias=True)
        self.norm = nn.BatchNorm1d(out_channels, eps=1e-3, momentum=0.01)

    def forward(self, inputs):
        x = self.linear(inputs)
        ## uncomment for batch normalization
        # x = self.norm(x.permute(0, 2, 1).contiguous()).permute(0, 2, 1).contiguous()
        x = F.relu(x)
        return x

class KerasModel(models.Model):
    def __init__(self,
                 num_filters):
        super(KerasModel, self).__init__()

        my_layers = []
        BN = layers.BatchNormalization(name='my_bn', momentum=0.01, epsilon=1e-3)
        LIN = layers.Dense(num_filters, name='my_linear', activation=None, use_bias=True)
        my_layers.append([LIN, BN])
        self.my_layers = my_layers

    def call(self, ins):
        x = self.my_layers[0][0](tf.convert_to_tensor(ins))
        ## uncomment for batch normalization
        # x = self.my_layers[0][1](x)
        x = tf.nn.relu(x)
        return x

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # create dummy input
    np.random.seed(0)
    input_np = np.random.rand(4,5,6)
    filters = 8

    keras_l = KerasModel(num_filters=filters)

    tf_features = keras_l(tf.convert_to_tensor(input_np))

    pytorch_l = PytorchModel(in_channels=6,
                             out_channels=filters)

    # copy weights from keras model to pytorch model
    new_state_dict = OrderedDict()
    new_state_dict['linear.weight'] = torch.from_numpy(np.transpose(keras_l.layers[0].weights[0].numpy(), (1, 0)))
    new_state_dict['linear.bias'] = torch.from_numpy(keras_l.layers[0].bias.numpy())
    ## uncomment for batch normalization
    # new_state_dict['norm.weight'] = torch.from_numpy(keras_l.layers[1].weights[0].numpy())  # gamma
    # new_state_dict['norm.bias'] = torch.from_numpy(keras_l.layers[1].weights[1].numpy())  # bias
    # new_state_dict['norm.running_mean'] = torch.from_numpy(keras_l.layers[1].weights[2].numpy())
    # new_state_dict['norm.running_var'] = torch.from_numpy(keras_l.layers[1].weights[3].numpy())
    pytorch_l.load_state_dict(new_state_dict, strict=False)

    batch_input_voxels_np = torch.from_numpy(input_np).float()
    batch_pytorch_features = pytorch_l.forward(batch_input_voxels_np)

    # => check how results differ, when batch normalization is applied.
    print(tf_features[0, 0, :])
    print(pytorch_features[0, 0, :])
```

Comment: How are you determining that normalization does not work, and why are you setting the BN momentum to 0.01? You are not doing that in PyTorch and it will completely change the estimation of running mean and variances.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro corrected the code. I do set the same values for both BN versions. I determine it in such a way, that x == x_bn_k (whatever axis i try to apply BN on) , while x != x_bn_py

Comment: still setting the momentum so low is a problem, why are you doing this? When I ask how you compare, you should include code for that as well.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro, for now I compare with simple print statements as I expect BN to do the same for both keras and pytorch. Added results.
I saw such low value of momentum in some example and took it over. Can also change it, but should it not cause this discrepancy between keras and pytorch results, I guess.

Comment: Ok, you should make a self-contained code example, because if I run your keras code I get errors like "Layer dense_1 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor.", which makes sense as you can't give non-symbolic inputs to Keras layers. So I cannot reproduce your results. Also I looked at the keras BN implementation and the default weight initialization make it behave like the identity transformation, which explain your results.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro, sure, I will update with self contained example. I thought at the beginning that I am missing some point that could be seen on conceptual level. Thanks for trying to help. Now, code is a minimal running example.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro. Agreed: default weight initialization makes it behave like identity. I changed init of BN for *moving_mean_initializer=Constant(value=0.5)* and *moving_variance_initializer=Constant(value=0.25)* in keras model and observed that it worked. However, pytorch model shall behave exactly the same since the weights are transferred, yet it does not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BatchNorm momentum convention PyTorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345857/batchnorm-momentum-convention-pytorch)

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget

```
pytorch_l.eval()
```

and

```
with torch.no_grad():
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
with torch.no_grad():
    pytorch_l.eval()
    batch_pytorch_features = pytorch_l(batch_input_voxels_np)
```